# Postgresql Database Connection on Android Studio

Tags: android, postgresql, jdbc

I want to connect postgresql database server system on Android Studio.But I cant connect because DriverManager.getConnection return null.How can I connect postgresql database server?

```
 protected void connectionTest() {
        java.sql.Connection conn = null;
        try {
            final String mysqlConnUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://***.***.***.***:5432/databaseName";
            try {

                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.setProperty("user", "root");
                props.setProperty("password", "root");
                props.setProperty("ssl", "true");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlConnUrl, props);

            } catch (NoClassDefFoundError i) {
                i.printStackTrace();
            }
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have a error when run connectionTest class:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.Locale$Category

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlConnUrl, "root", "root");
```